# How do i enable 3d textures in carla simulator

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 3d

When I try implementing  `./CarlaUE4.sh` I always receive this message:

```
../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2105: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: 
CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.
```

Does anybody know a way to remove or solve such a thing?

Comment: Have you searched the error? What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: i have tried to search how to enable the 3D texture or what is CCS but i haven't found a clue.

Comment: i also tried to check my NVIDIA driver and GPU but its all working perfectly.